# If the output is 0.09, does this mean that the prediction is class 1 or 0?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, binary-classification, sigmoid

I use a Keras EfficientNetB7 and transfer learning to solve a binary classification problem. I use `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)` for my final layer.

My labels are encoded as the following for the model.fit():

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
  ...
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]]
```

My question is about the output of the `model.predict()`. For example, if the output is `[[0.09122807]]`, does this mean that the prediction is class 1. or 0.?

Initially, I assumed it would have been class 0. but my model predicts the opposite of this assumption. In some stackoverflow posts, I saw that the output should be used 1 - p where p is the probability of class 1.

There is conflicting information on the net; hence, wanted to ask your guidance.

Comment: It is nearer to 0 than 1 which means the result label is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using binary cross-entropy as loss function, the output of Sigmoid functions represent the probability of $\mathbb{P}[y=1]$. Hence, it means that $\mathbb{P}[y=0] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[y=1]$.
Therefore, when the output is $0.09$, it means that the prediction is $y=0$ as it is more probable ($1-0.09 = 0.91$).